# remove unbind attribute in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I disabled the click event of image using unbind method. But I don't know how to recover the click event again.
Here is the code,

`<img src="testimg.jpg" id="sub_form">`

disabled the click event of above image using the code

```
$('#sub_form').unbind('click');
```

How do i recover the click event? I tried with the bind event

```
  $('#sub_form').bind('click');
```

but it wont work.

Why I'm going for click event of image is ajax form submission. The code is,

```
$("#sub_form").click(function() {
var input_data = $('#testform').serialize();
    $.ajax({ 
//my code
});
});
```

how can i achieve this after unbind of image is performed.

Comment: `.bind()` has two methods. You need to pass in the function reference when rebinding.

Comment: you need to add the handler parameter as the 2nd parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you saved the handler, you can just invoke it again:

```
var handler = function() {
    alert('click');
};

$('#sub_form').click(handler);

// disabling:
$('#sub_form').unbind('click', handler);

// reenabling:
$('#sub_form').click(handler);
```

If you don’t know what handlers that are bound, you can find and save them before unbinding:

```
// save the click handlers
var events = $('#sub_form').data('events'),
    handlers = 'click' in events ? Array.prototype.slice.call(events.click) : [],
    handler = function() {
        $.each(handlers, function() {
            this.handler();
        });
    };

// disable
$('#sub_form').unbind('click');

// reenable
$('#sub_form').bind('click', handler);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sPPnE/

Comment: Added another way to retrieve the handler if you don’t have it saved in a variable.

Comment: Im new to the jquery. Please refer this fiddle for the code i have with yopur answer. But it wont work, correct me if im wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/sPPnE/24/

Comment: @designersvsoft I think you might be asking the wrong questions. If you are trying to detect a checkbox, place the logic in the click handler: http://jsfiddle.net/sPPnE/25/

Comment: Thank u David. It's working fine. Im not only displayed the image field in my project. i disabled entire form when the checkbox is checked. That's why im going for that long process. But your solution is the best way to disable the click event. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a `function reference` when calling `.unbind()`:

For instance:

```
function myHandler( event ) {
}

// bind the click handler
$('#sub_form').bind('click', myHandler);

// remove only this exact click handler
$('#sub_form').unbind('click', myHandler);

// bind it again
$('#sub_form').bind('click', myHandler);
```

**Sidenote**: As for jQuery 1.7.x you should use the `.on()` and `.off()` equivalent methods.

Reference: [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/), [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But why im going for the click event of image is, ajax form submission.How can i achieve this with the above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the event handler with a function to run when the event occurs, try this:

```
$('#sub_form').bind('click', function() {
    alert("You clicked #sub_form");
});
```

If you are going to be binding/unbinding regularly, it would be best to put the logic into it's own function so that it can be easily rebound:

```
$("#element").click(function() {
    $("#sub_form").unbind();

    // do something

    $("#sub_form").bind('click', myFunc);
});

function myFunc() {
    alert("You clicked #sub_form");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But why im going for the click event of image is, ajax form submission.How can i achieve this with the above?